# Replace a link HTML with non existing tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have images that opens in lightbox. I'm trying to make one image not open in lightbox. Best way to do it, is if I change `<a href...></a>` to `<b href></b>`, so it doesn't have function, `span` what ever.

My jQuery:

```
$('.post-101 a').replaceWith(function () {
    return $('.post-101 b', {
        html: $(this).html()
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can unbind all events using [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```
$('.post-101 a').off();
```

Answer (score 2):

Broken html is not a good idea. Try catching the click event and stop it form going to lightbox plugin.

Something like this might work.

```
$( "a.no-lightbox" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

More info on [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)